# No sound/audio after resuming from sleep

Tags: sound, 13.10, suspend, lenovo

I've made a fresh UEFI install of Ubuntu 13.10 (64 bit) on a Lenovo Ideapad Z510 laptop with Intel i5 4200M processor. Ubuntu is the only OS installed on the computer, secure boot disabled. Everythings works fine (backlight issue fixed after editing rc.local file), the only minor trouble I have is resuming the laptop from "sleep" mode.

If I close the lid and then wake the laptop opening it again, there is no audio/sound. I need to restart the computer (not even logging out helps). If I suspend the computer in a graphical way (not closing the lid): gearwheel in top right of the screen -- suspend and wake it up/turning on, audio works with no issues. Ideas how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: I saw one blog where the guy says the Wifi does not work with Z510's Intel Centrino wiki controller. I have also ordered the same expected to arrive by end of December.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you could try. First of all try restart the pulse audio daemon:

```
pulseaudio -k      # Kill the pulse audio process. It should restart by itself
```

You can also check if there are any messages related to pulse audio in the kernel ring buffer:

```
dmesg | grep pulse
```

If there any error messages, you could post them for us to take a look at.

Comment: didn't work for me, i always have to restart

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea which of these did the trick, but I was not able to get the command:

```
/usr/bin/pasuspender /bin/true
```

or

```
pulseaudio -k
```

to fix anything.

I added my user to the groups **plugdev** (of which my primary admin account was already a member) and **pulse-access** (of which neither were members).

This was never a problem before I created the second user, so I assume it was an issue with group membership in **plugdev**.