# no sound in Ubuntu 14.04 x64

Tags: sound

After every "suspend-wake'up" my computer have no sound. 
I must "renew" sound in these two steps:

1. System settings>sound>input device, I shall microphone probe.
2. System settings>sound>test sound.

Then sound in my computer working properly.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1355025) that seems to relate to this issue and it seems [related to running apps incompatible with pulseaudio 4.0](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1355025/comments/7).  On my system if a PA compatible app is run last before the suspend, the bug is much less likely to occur.  An answer to a similar question [suggests killing pulseaudio](https://askubuntu.com/a/372438/322753) (it restarts automatically).  Creating an executable script "00custom" in /etc/pm/sleep.d that plays a sound and resets pulseaudio before suspending completely fixed the problem on my system.  You need a Snoring.wav file in your Downloads folder for example [this](http://soundbible.com/1634-Snoring.html).

```
#!/bin/bash

# custom suspend resume stuff
#
# 1) play a suspend sound and reset pulseaudio to workaround Bug #1355025
#

DBUS_USERNAME=$(grep -z "USER" /proc/$(pidof gnome-session)/environ | cut -d= -f2-)
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(/usr/bin/id -u $DBUS_USERNAME)
export HOME=/home/$DBUS_USERNAME

case "$1" in
        hibernate|suspend)

                # play a suspend sound and reset pulseaudio
                /usr/bin/sudo -E -u $DBUS_USERNAME /bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/aplay /home/$DBUS_USERNAME/Downloads/Snoring.wav"
                /usr/bin/sudo -E -u $DBUS_USERNAME /bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/pulseaudio -k"

                ;;
        *) exit
                ;;
esac
```